# What kind of charger do I use for HP Compaq Presario CQ35?

Tags: laptop

My mom gave me an unused laptop and the charger is missing. 
I would like to buy a new one but i don't know what kind.

Comment: Harry has kindly done the research for you, but this information is on the sticker under the laptop - any laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You need a laptop charger that supports 18.5V and 3.5A and is compatible with the
HP Compaq Presario CQ35. If buying on the internet, ensure that the wall plug
is compatible with your country.

Some random examples : [example1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ARyee-Charger-Compatible-Presario-Probook/dp/B07RZ388S7/ref=pd_sbs_147_3/258-7418264-5440253?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07RZ388S7&pd_rd_r=5c98bf4a-d32c-441d-8c7f-03f6b487b4c4&pd_rd_w=u7ODY&pd_rd_wg=MNrmn&pf_rd_p=f4a31d1d-8f61-48f5-b6f4-a22ba06df575&pf_rd_r=5FX0PHFWMBCBF6MB348Y&psc=1&refRID=5FX0PHFWMBCBF6MB348Y)
and
[example2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0785JD7RG).

Comment: I recently had a similar situation, guess where I bought my laptop charger and cable, Ali-Express. Do note, the charger usually does not include the powercord, but they are easy to find. (at ali Express that is. The link here on Amazon does have it. But it is something to check for.)